# Android AlarmManager setRepeating Issue

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager

I'm developing a feeder application, and i have the option that let the user choose for each source (feed source) specify the time to get data from the internet and update the database.

I'm using AlarmManager for this.

What i do tipically is:

Get all providers.
Group in a map> that the key is the sleep time and value is a list of providers

For what?...

Well i iterate later over this dictionary for each key and schedule an alarm to send a broadcast with data in a intent.

In my broadcast receiver i want to get this data..

The problem that i am not undestanding is i pass a Key (sleep time) in a for each loop to schedule the event... actually i got 2 keys, [5, 10]

and on my onreceive i get only key 5.. 2 times.... it seems like the same intent is delivered to the receiver..

Here is the code:

```
private void setAlarmForEnabledProviders(HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Provider>> map)
        {
            Context ctx = FeederPeriodicalUpdater.this;
            AlarmManager alarmMngr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            for(Integer key : map.keySet())
            {
                int keyValue = key.intValue();
                Intent intent = new Intent(FeederPeriodicalUpdater.this, OnAlarmReceiver.class);


                intent.putExtra(AlarmManager_IntentKey, keyValue);
                PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 0, intent, 0);

                long firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                alarmMngr.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, firstTime, pIntent);
            }               
        }
```

My Receiver:

```
public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) 
{
    Log.d(TAG, "onReceive");

    application = (DroidApplication)ctx.getApplicationContext();
    feedMessageService = application.getFeedMessageService();

    int sleep = intent.getIntExtra(FeederPeriodicalUpdater.AlarmManager_IntentKey, -1);

    if(sleep == -1)
        throw new IllegalStateException();
```

Comment: I'm glad you're trying to implement the design that i gave you in your previous question there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166333/android-long-service-create-bg-thread-and-i-dont-know-that-is-going-on/ Accept my answer maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change the request code as the second parameter of the getBroadcast() of the PendingIntent

```
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, "here change the value everytime", intent, 0);
```

like pass the unique number because you send the same intent and request i think it will be overwrite

Comment: That's right, i was typing the same answer, try it like that.

Comment: Thanks is that.. I really appreciate your help.
The documentation is at least weak...
Here is what it says....

Retrieve a PendingIntent that will perform a broadcast, like calling Context.sendBroadcast().
Parameters

context The Context in which this PendingIntent should perform the broadcast.
requestCode Private request code for the sender (currently not used).
intent The Intent to be broadcast.

Comment: 3 factory method... i suppose now that is implemented something like a dictionary that returns to me the cached version of the key... so when i use second time and dont pass nothing, the value returned to me is the same.......